# Push notifications - from Today Extension - iOS

Tags: ios, push-notification, today-extension

Is it possible to send push notification from Today Extension widget? No need to receive and handle the notification via the extension - just to send it.

Comment: you don't send push notification from client app, push notification is initiated from your server and APNS takes care of sending notifications to devices

Comment: @SandeepBhandari Do you mean that I don't need the push token to be able to send the notification - just to make a call to the server. The app is responsible of handling the notification.

Comment: You send device token from your parent app to server as soon as app is installed intact every time its quit n launched. You dont do it from your extension. Finally once your server has the token it can initiate communication to APNS whenever it wants what you can do though is you can trigger API of your server from extension and API can further initiate Push notification

Comment: @SandeepBhandari Thank you for you response. So I register for notifications in the parent app and then just make an API call to the server from the extension and the server imitates the notification sending. If I got it right and you want to you can put your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Yes you got it correct!